# How to get the reference to a model object instance in Magento

Tags: magento

I am creating a module dealing with a registration process which requires a certain amount of registration fee from its user. the basic flow is 1)user inputs personal information in the first page, and posts the form to the second page 2) user reviews the information in the second page which contains a PayPal button. 3) after confirmation, user clicks the PayPal button and is redirected the PayPal payment page 4) user is redirected to a success page if transaction is finished or to a cancel page if transaction not finished. I created a table called 'registration' that holds the general info for a registration such as id, register name and etc. In the 'PostAction' function (related to the second page), I set the model attributes by using info from the posted form, but do not call the save() method which I think should be done in the SuccesAction (related to success page). My question is how to get the reference to the model object in the SuccessAction so I can use the save() method to insert it into the database. Also, any suggestion or idea to improve the module is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration object/model is disposed as soon as the 'postAction' page completes. You cannot get it back unless it has been saved *somewhere*. That somewhere could be a session variable, but those can expire when you least expect it (see [Finagle's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finagle%27s_law)) so saving to the database is better. Either a separate table or by marking the registration with a status to show it is not yet complete - the 'successAction' would complete the process by setting that marker then saving again.

As an example consider how orders pass through checkout. Until the customer gets to the last step and submits the order, it is only a quote and has been saved in the `sales_flat_quote` table so far. After that point it is saved in `sales_flat_order` instead.